# Nest Doorbell 2nd generation Interior chime buzzing not ringing

Tags: nest, doorbell

Today I got a nest doorbell 2nd generation and installed it. Doorbell chime is working fine but interior chime ringing is not working it’s buzzing when you press the door bell.

Here is the screenshot of chime connector is wired-in. I feel there could be wrong connection in here. Any thoughts?

Other than white puck chime connector everything else was already in there as is.

[image]